# CruiseControl not merging testresults from MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, integration-testing, mstest, cruisecontrol.net

I've got an integration build set up with CruiseControl and according to the ccnet.log file, it's merging in my test results, but when I look through the log, I can't find any signs of them and the build page says there were no tests run (even though they were run)...

Here are the last 3 lines from CCNET.LOG:

```
2013-01-29 08:02:51,325 [GEMS - Continuous Integration:INFO] Merging file 'E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\TestResults\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.trx'
2013-01-29 08:02:51,325 [GEMS - Continuous Integration:INFO] Merging file 'E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\TestResults\GEMS.Web.UnitTests.trx'
2013-01-29 08:02:51,325 [GEMS - Continuous Integration:INFO] Integration complete: Success - 1/29/2013 8:02:46 AM
```

Those paths and filenames are correct. I verified it. Also, if they weren't, there would be an error (I know because I originally mistyped the directory name).

Those files appear to be perfectly valid MSTest .trx files with the information from the test results. I'm running VS.NET 2012, if that matters...

Here's the result summary from a one of the files:

```
<ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="24" executed="24" passed="24" error="0" failed="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
</ResultSummary>
```

But the build results from the CruiseControl web page show:

```
Suites run: 0, Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0seconds 
No Tests Run 
This project doesn't have any tests
```

The test runs are clearly showing up in the log, as can be seen from the log of the final MSBuild task (note that this is different from the .trx files that I'm merging. This is simply console logging captured by CCNET).

```
<msbuild startTime="01/28/2013 16:31:36" elapsedTime="00:00:12" elapsedSeconds="132" success="true">
  <project name="Coverage" file="E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\Coverage.xml" startTime="01/28/2013 16:31:37" elapsedTime="00:00:11" elapsedSeconds="131" success="true">
    <target name="Coverage" startTime="01/28/2013 16:31:38" elapsedTime="00:00:10" elapsedSeconds="130" success="true">
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[E:\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" -output:"E:\GEMS_Build\Integration_Artifacts\0.1.1.270\OpenCover\shared.coverage.xml" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\src\GEMS.Shared\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests\bin\Debug\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.dll /resultsfile:E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\TestResults\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.trx" -filter:"+[GEMS.Shared]* -[GEMS.Shared]GEMS.Shared.PerformanceCounters* -[GEMS.Shared]GEMS.Shared.Cache.* " -mergebyhash]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.50727.1]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[    ]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Loading E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\src\GEMS.Shared\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests\bin\Debug\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.dll...]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Starting execution...]]></message>
      <message level="high" />
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Results               Top Level Tests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[-------               ---------------]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ANDFilterTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.BasicFilterTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ComplexFilterTranslationTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ComplexParameterDictionaryTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.FilterEncodeDecodeTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.FilterRolloverTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.IsNullFilterTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ORFilterTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.SimpleEncodedFilterTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ValidateComplexExpressionTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ValidateFieldsTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.FilterTests.ValidateTranslateTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Data.JsonTests.ComplexJsonObjectConversionTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetDaysInMonthTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetEndOfLastMonthTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetEndOfLastYearTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetEndOfMonthTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetEndOfYearTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetLastWeekOfMonthTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetStartOfLastMonthTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetStartOfLastYearTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetStartOfMonthTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetStartOfYearTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetWeekOfMonthTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.GetWeekOfYearTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.MaxDateTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Date.DateTimeExtensionTests.MinDateTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Enums.EnumMapperTests.EnumMapperSimpleFail1Test]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Enums.EnumMapperTests.EnumMapperSimpleFail2Test]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Enums.EnumMapperTests.EnumMapperSimpleSuccessfultTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Security.ActiveDirectoryHelperUnitTests.AuthenticateUserTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Security.ActiveDirectoryHelperUnitTests.GetADUserInfoTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Security.ActiveDirectoryHelperUnitTests.GetAllUsersTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Security.ActiveDirectoryHelperUnitTests.IsInGroupTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Tasks.AsyncHelperTests.NoParameter]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Tasks.AsyncHelperTests.NoParameterWithCallback]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Tasks.AsyncHelperTests.OneParameterNoCallback]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Tasks.AsyncHelperTests.OneParameterWithCallback]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Text.StringExtensionsTests.DeleteLinesTest]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Text.StringExtensionsTests.IsNullOrEmptyTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Text.StringExtensionsTests.TestPlurals]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Text.StringExtensionsTests.ToDateTimeTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Passed                GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.Text.StringExtensionsTests.ToEnumTests]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[43/43 test(s) Passed]]></message>
      <message level="high" />
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Summary]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[-------]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Test Run Completed.]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[  Passed  43]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[  ----------]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[  Total   43]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Results file:  E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\TestResults\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.trx]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Test Settings: Default Test Settings]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Committing...]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Visited Classes 20 of 26 (76.9230769230769)]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Visited Methods 74 of 102 (72.5490196078431)]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Visited Points 533 of 718 (74.2339832869081)]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Visited Branches 141 of 243 (58.0246913580247)]]></message>
      <message level="high" />
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Alternative Visited Classes 21 of 27 (77.7777777777778)]]></message>
      <message level="high"><![CDATA[Alternative Visited Methods 91 of 125 (72.8)]]></message>

.... and it goes on and on with the other unit tests, but 
I showed the above just to demonstrate that my unit tests are in fact being run

    </target>
  </project>
</msbuild>
```

This is the publishers section from my ccnet.config

```
<publishers>
    <statistics />
    <xmllogger />
    <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                   cleanUpValue="50" />
    <buildpublisher>
        <sourceDir>E:\GEMS_Build\Integration\TestResults\</sourceDir>
        <publishDir>E:\GEMS_Build\Integration_Artifacts\</publishDir>
        <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
    </buildpublisher>
    <merge>
        <files>
            <file>TestResults\GEMS.Shared.UnitTests.trx</file>
            <file>TestResults\GEMS.Web.UnitTests.trx</file>
        </files>
    </merge>
</publishers>
```

I've searched the entire build log looking for words from tags in my .trx files. Words like **TestResult**, **TestDefinitions**, **ResultSummary**, etc... I can't find them (other than the word TestResult appearing as part of the path name). The .trx files are clearly not being merged in.... What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have your merge after xmllogger

Source:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task

Comment: Thank you SO much. This has been dogging me for weeks. Way to earn your first rep points, answering an upvoted question over 2 weeks old!